# CorePlot setGridLinesRange only for majorGridLine

Tags: cocoa-touch, core-plot

I've set my majorGridLines with:

```
[x setGridLinesRange:[CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat(1.0f)
                                                       length:CPTDecimalFromFloat(201.0f)]];
```

and now I'm trying to figure out how to set it only for the major and not for the minor too. 
Is there a way to affect only the major? 
Because I try to get a grid like this:

```
   Y
   ^
4  |   |   |   |   |   |
3  |   |   |   |   |   |
2  |   |   |   |   |   |
1  |   |   |   |   |   |
0  | |   |   |   |   |
   ----------------------> X
   0   1   2   3   4   5
```

Thanks for any Help! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, but you can make a second x-axis that only draws minor gridlines. Each axis can have different values for the `gridLinesRange`.